# OpenGL ES 2.0 Vertex Lighting inconsistencies

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I am setting up my lighting as below. The issue is that it looks like there is one giant light in the middle (as you can see on the sphere screenshot below). The goal is to have 3 lights in a triangle shape with each individual light being seen on the sphere (this is the bottom screenshot). To accomplish this, do I need to create each light as a "spotlight"? I noticed `GLKEffectPropertyLight` does have properties for this but am uncertain if this is the effect I'm going for.

```
- (void)setupLighting
{
   // setup the lighting
   self.lightingType = GLKLightingTypePerPixel;
   self.colorMaterialEnabled = GL_TRUE;

   // light positions
   GLKVector4 light0Pos = GLKVector4Make(0.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f, 1.0f);
   GLKVector4 light1Pos = GLKVector4Make(-2.0f, -2.0f, 40.0f, 1.0f);
   GLKVector4 light2Pos = GLKVector4Make(2.0f, -2.0f, 40.0f, 1.0f);
   GLKVector4 frontLightDif = GLKVector4Make(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);

   // specular, diffuse and ambient colors
   GLKVector4 specular = GLKVector4Make(0.45f, 0.45f, 0.45f, 1.0f);
   GLKVector4 diffuse = GLKVector4Make(0.15f, 0.15f, 0.15f, 1.0f);
   GLKVector4 ambient = GLKVector4Make(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);

   // setup light 0 - ambient light
   self.light0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
   self.light0.position = light0Pos;
   self.light0.ambientColor = ambient;
   self.light0.diffuseColor = specular;
   self.light0.specularColor = specular;

   // setup light 1 - head on light
   self.light1.enabled = GL_TRUE;
   self.light1.position = light1Pos;
   self.light1.diffuseColor = frontLightDif;
   self.light1.specularColor = specular;

   // setup light 2
   self.light2.enabled = GL_TRUE;
   self.light2.position = light2Pos;
   self.light2.diffuseColor = diffuse;
   self.light2.specularColor = specular;
}
```

[image: Incorrect sphere lighting]

[image: Correct sphere lighting]

Comment: Image is broken. Also, can you provide vertex+fragment shaders code too?

Comment: I am not using any shaders on my end. I'm using Apple's GLKit framework to handle this. Essentially I provide color data per vertex. In this case each vertex contains the same color so I would expect the color to be a smooth blend. I'll see if I can fix the image - it works when I view the question. It looks like 2 vertices contain the colors then the color gets darker near the middle of the square.

Comment: Some code would be helpful, but anyway: have you tried to disable lights? Something like `effect.light0.enabled = GL_FALSE;`

Comment: I need lighting for my viewer, but looks like that may be the issue. I turned the lights off and the colors looked fine. I may have to tweak my lighting to make it appear how I want. I posted my lighting code above if you see something that would cause the squares to appear so dark.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have three lights in your scene and some of them are casting shadows on your polygons because they emits light from opposite positions. Try to create a single light source positioned above your polygons and see what happens.

Comment: Right now they should be in some sort of triangle, wouldn't this apply light from the necessary directions? The user of the viewer can rotate the model so light hits the polygons from which ever angle. How would you recommend setting up 3 lights? I will see what happens with 1 light but eventually I'm going to need to use all 3 lights.